# Nested Firebase observers experiencing slowdown

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am seeing a dramatic slowdown in firebase realtime DB queries for an observe I setup in another observer setup's callback.

```
func setupUserStatsObservers() {
    let orderedByKey = UserManager.shared.loggedInUserMode == .pro ? "pro_current_leaderboard_rank" : "play_current_leaderboard_rank"

    //get ref
    let userStatsNodeRef = FirRefs.USER_STATS_REF
    let start = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    log.debug("start: \(start)")
    let userStatsChildAddedHandle = userStatsNodeRef
        .queryOrdered(byChild: orderedByKey)
        .queryStarting(atValue: 1)
        .queryLimited(toFirst: 1)
        .observe(.childAdded, with: {[weak self] (userStatsSnapshot) in
        log.debug("test1 took : \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) - start")
        if userStatsSnapshot.exists(){
            let userIDStr = userStatsSnapshot.key
            let userID = Int(userIDStr)!
            log.debug("received user_stats for: \(userIDStr)")
            log.debug("started nested observer setup \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - start) seconds after start")
            FirRefs.USER_INFO_REF.child(userIDStr).observe(.value, with: {[weak self] (userInfoSnapshot) in
                log.debug("midpoint pt 2: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - start)")
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                if userInfoSnapshot.exists(){
                    if let globalLeader = GlobalLeader.init(userStatsSnapshot: userStatsSnapshot, userInfoSnapshot: userInfoSnapshot){
                        strongSelf.leadersDict[userID] = globalLeader
                        log.debug("completion took \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - start) seconds")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    })

    observerRegister[userStatsChildAddedHandle] = userStatsNodeRef
    ....
```

Both queries performed slowly (several seconds) until I turned off Database.database().persistenceEnabled. After that, the outer query observer performed quickly (50-100ms).

Debug output:

```
16:00:16.146  DEBUG - test1 took : -0.371608018875122
16:00:16.148  DEBUG - received user_stats for: 2967162804267512
16:00:16.149  DEBUG - started nested observer setup 0.371876001358032 seconds after start
16:00:23.227  DEBUG - midpoint pt 2: 7.45274090766907
16:00:23.228  DEBUG - completion took 7.45316910743713 seconds
```

If I make a one-off observer similar to the nested observer, the performance is fast, i.e.

```
FirRefs.USER_INFO_REF.child("2967734475866416").observe(.value, with: {[weak self] (userInfoSnapshot) in
        ...
})
```

This is what the relevant nodes in firebase look like.[image: user_stats][image: user_info]

Comment: Please don't put images in questions; images make us have to retype that data if we want to use it in an answer. See [No Images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). The code looks ok but we don't know what code is within other functions and classes (GlobalLeader) that could be contributing to the issue.

Comment: Did some testing by copy and pasting your code and duplicating your structure. Here's what the results were: *received user_stats for: 296773
started nested observer setup 0.0901312828063965 seconds after start
midpoint pt 2: 0.16417407989502 completion took 0.16420316696167 seconds*. The numbers were faster with persistenceEnabled. Again though, I had to comment out the classes and calls that were omitted from the question. My results would be improved with .indexOn as well. think your issue lies outside the code in the question.

Comment: Oh - and using *.observe(.value* on the 'inside' observer is probably not needed as you are not watching for changes in that node. The 'outside' observer will fire whenever a new user_stat is added that matches the query anyway and that's when you want to lookup the user. So change the 'inner' observe to *.observeSingleEvent(of: .value*